# Progress bar in react with 1 sec increment not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple progress bar in react with 1sec increment but the the progress shows 2% increment at once. can someone please let me know what's wrong with this code and why it shows 2% increment instead of 1%.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prev) => {
        if (prev < 100) {
          return prev + 1;
        }
        if (prev === 100) {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
        return prev;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Complete code is available in this codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/progress-bar-in-react-ccty7w?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [React's Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) is enabled, your `useEffect` with no dependencies is actually called twice. Which cause two timers to be created.

You could move `timer` const outside the `useEffect` and check if it is already set. To make it live between further re-renders, you could move it in a `useRef`.

See the following fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/progress-bar-in-react-forked-ewdnuf

Answer (score 0):

***useEffect Run Twice in React v18.0.***

That's why the progress bar starts from 2.

If you need to run once, you can disable strict mode in ***index.js*** file which is not recommended.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode> // remove strict mode from here, not recommended
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

More on details [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93)

In production build, it'll be solved and useEffect hook will be called only once.